# SSIS Lookup task - setting the SQL Command programatically

Tags: c#, ssis

I have found a work around when trying to programatically set the SQLCommand to the lookup task in SSIS using C#.

Original issue: Directly through the lookup task in design time

```
        CManagedComponentWrapper designTime = lookupTask.Instantiate();
        designTime.ProvideComponentProperties();
        designTime.SetComponentProperty("SqlCommand", lookupQuery);
        designTime.SetComponentProperty("SqlCommandParam", lookupQuery);
```

New issue: Through the Data Flow task that hosts the Lookup transformation task:

```
        satelliteDft.SetExpression("[MyLookup].[SqlCommand]", lookupQuery);
        satelliteDft.SetExpression("[MyLookup].[SqlCommandParam]", lookupQuery);
```

The issue is that even when going through the data flow task, when I open the newly created package the select statement does not show up in the lookup task.

EDIT:

The solutions below do not modify the actual value in the lookup task, even if the data flow properties have indeed changed. The properties available for modification in the data flow task are the following:

```
[MyLookup].[SqlCommand]
[MyLookup].[SqlCommandParam]
AutoGenerateIDForNewObjects
BLOBTempStoragePath
BufferManager
BufferTempStoragePath
ComponentMetaDataCollection
CreationName
DefaultBufferMaxRows
DefaultBufferSize
DelayValidation
Description
Disable
DisableEventHandlers
EngineThreads
EventHandlers
EventInfos
Events
ExecutionDuration
ExecutionResult
ExecutionStatus
FailPackageOnFailure
FailParentOnFailure
ForcedExecutionValue
ForceExecutionResult
ForceExecutionValue
ID
IsDefaultLocaleID
IsolationLevel
LocaleID
LogEntryInfos
LoggingMode
LoggingOptions
MaximumErrorCount
Name
Parent
PathCollection
RunInOptimizedMode
StartTime
StopTime
TransactionOption
VariableDispenser
Variables
```

I think the idea is to be able to use one of these to set the value of the Expression.

Comment: When you view the raw XML code of the package, is that PropertyExpression value set as anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are setting the expression and not the task property directly, you'll have to put the query in quotes so that the expression is properly set and can be evaluated by SSIS.

So something like

```
satelliteDft.SetExpression("[MyLookup].[SqlCommand]", string.Format("\"{0}\"", lookupQuery));
```

should probably fare better.

UPDATE: So first let's get terminology straight.

In SSIS, there are Expressions and there are Properties.

The property you want to affect is the SqlCommand property of the MyLookup task.
You can affect this in three ways:

1. Setting the property on the lookup task directly.
2. Setting the property [MyLookup].[SqlCommand] on the data flow task containing the lookup task directly.
3. Setting the Expression value of the [MyLookup].[SqlCommand] property in the data flow task.

Points number 1 and 2 are modifying the exact same property - the lookup task's SQLCommand property. If you change either one, you can see the results of the change in the other box in the GUI. The value itself is only stored in one place in the XML - as the Lookup component element's SQLCommand property element's text value.

The third one is trickier. WHen you set it in the GUI, it also sets the value of the evaluated expression to the Lookup task's SQLCommand property. It does this under the hood. When you do this programmatically, it does not do this under-the-hood evaluation and property-setting and hence your error.

This is the same issue you're having when you set the [MyLookup].[SqlCommand] property on your Data Flow Task - that isn't being propagated to the Lookup task.

Comment: The Expression is indeed changed, but it is not displayed in the Lookup task when opened in the designer.

Comment: Updated to explain what's happening.

Comment: Why in your Original issue did setting the SQLCommand property on the lookup task directly not work? Also, I highly recommend EzAPI as a much simpler and direct tool for building SSIS packages programmatically.

Comment: That`s unfortunate; I hoped that this would be programatically possible. Thanks for your help Kyle.

Comment: Do you know if EzAPI handles this particular issue? It is the only one left that I have encountered in building my own framework.

Comment: It does, or rather, I set the SqlCommand property of EzLookups all the time without issue.